# AWS Api Gateway: Missing Authentication Token Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, amazon-dynamodb

I am testing out this proof of concept. However, I am getting **Missing Authentication Token** after adding the role into the lambda function that I created to run on API gateway. I am currently following below references to invoke lambda function + dynamodb + api gateway with Java.

After giving the access with IAM role. I am still having the same error. Please help to advice. Thank you all!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbCNVApI4lA&ab_channel=MadeEasy

https://github.com/enquiresandeep/AWSSamples

---

screenshots

[image: Postman GET error]

[image: AWS role attached to lambda function]

[image: AWS role solution with dynamoDB access]

Comment: If you are using IAM authentication, you need to add the appropriate Authorization header via AWS v4 signing process.  I believe Postman can generate these for you but you need to enable those and sign the request with your role (ie add the headers).

Comment: Thanks bro for the kind guidance! I added the access and secret key from AWS and it works. Thank you so much! This is the video url i used too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNQX08KSmLY&ab_channel=BabarSiddiqui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JD D!

Obtain IAM access and secret key and add into Postman Authorization with AWS Signature before performing the API calls.

Reference Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNQX08KSmLY&ab_channel=BabarSiddiqui